# Cannot create a virtual table in SQL Server using c#

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a problem. I'm using Visual Studio 2013.

I cannot make my table a virtual table.

This is my code:

```
CREATE  TABLE [dbo].[Ime] 
(
     [Id]   INT            IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
     [Name] NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,
     [MD5]  NVARCHAR (MAX) NOT NULL,

     PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

And when I want to make it VIRTUAL by:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE [dbo].[Ime] 
    USING fts3(content TEXT);
```

It does not work. Can someone please explain to me the correct syntax ?

Comment: 'it doesn't work' is not an issue you are likely to get help on, not because of unwilling people but because of the lack of information to work on. please provide some technical detail about what is happening (error messages and such)

Comment: I already gave the error "message" and that is that the syntax is incorrect

Comment: maybe the actual error message is stuck in your keyboard because in the post there is no error message at all even after page reload.

Comment: CREATE VIRTUAL is a SQLLite  syntax for an interface to external storage. SQL Server has no such statement.

Comment: What do you mean by "virtual" table: View, Temporary Table or something else? Cryptic terminology isn't going to help here. https://www.idera.com/productssolutions/sqlserver/sqlvirtualdatabase for example is a "SQL Virtual Database" software solution that somehow I doubt is what was intended yet does use the terms SQL, Virtual and Database in the name of a product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FTS3 is an extension module in [SQLite](https://www.sqlite.org/docs.html), and is not applicable to Microsoft SQL Server.

The FTS modules must be enabled or else any SQL statement to create/drop an FTS3 or FTS4 tables will fail.

Refer to [Enabling FTS3 and FTS4](https://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#section_2) documentation.